# Using WhenEvent to Change the Sign of a Constant

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, event-detection

I am attempting to change the sign of a constant when a certain condition is met during a numerical integration. Here is the code:

```
μk = 0.3; g = 9.81; R = 1; ti = 0; m = 0.3;

EOM =  -μk (R θ'[t]^2 + g Sin[θ[t]]) + 
    g Cos[θ[t]] == R θ''[t];
IC1 =  θ'[0] == 0;  IC2 =  θ[0] == 0;

sol = NDSolve[{EOM, IC1, IC2, 
    WhenEvent[θ'[t] == 0, {μk = -μk; tf = t; 
    "RestartIntegration"}]}, θ[t], {t, ti, ∞}];

θ = θ[t] /. sol;
θd = D[θ[t] /. sol, t];
Plot[{θ, θd}, {t, ti, tf}]
```

The problem lies in the fact that it is not dissipating as it should.  `θ` should start to approach `Pi/2`.  Instead it oscillates on to `Infinity`.

Note: I discovered that I cannot simply use `Sign[θ'[t]]` since the value is crossing zero. A zero value is undesirable in my case.

[image: Slider System]

Here is an image of the system being modeled.

Comment: If I understand your last sentence correctly, you do not wish `μk == 0` when `θ'[t] == 0`,  What value do you wish it to have?

Comment: It should simply have a value that is +μk or -μk.

Comment: Yes, but which?  The issue is, what value should `μk` have, if a time-step lands exactly on `θ'[t] == 0`, which appears to be happening at `t == 2.062520756856687`?  You will notice that `μk` flips sign there, but `θ'[t] ` does not.  I can change this behavior, so that `uk` does not flip signs there, in which case the answer is entirely different.

Comment: Ah I understand you question now.  This is modeling a slider that oscillates in a vertical plane on a semicircular guide.  Thus, when θ'[t] == 0 the friction force is changing its direction.  Long story short, I am using when θ'[t] == 0 as a way to change the direction of the friction force.  Moving forward with my model I need to add a check that indicates if the direction of friction 'should' change as well as check static friction to see if the slider slips after the slider comes to rest.  I added a photo of the system to the original post.

Comment: In that case, why do you not wish to use `Sign[θ'[t]]`, which gives no friction when the slider is stationary?  Also, why is friction applied to the potential energy, g Sin[θ[t]]?

Comment: Sign[θ'[t]] probably can be used, in my mind, eliminating it seemed to be a possible way to go to give me more control over the process. I derived the EOM using Euler's second law and a set of n-t coordinates. What μk is multiplying (in parentheses) is the normal force.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code has three issues.  First, `μk` cannot be changed during the computation unless it is designated by `DiscreteVariables`.  Second, the list of actions to be taken by `WhenEvent` needs to be separated by commas, not semicolons.  Third, the upper limit of integration cannot be infinity.  With these changes, the code becomes

```
g = 9.81; R = 1; ti = 0; m = 0.3;

EOM =  -μk [t] (R θ'[t]^2 + g Sin[θ[t]]) + g Cos[θ[t]] == R θ''[t];
IC1 =  θ'[0] == 0;  IC2 =  θ[0] == 0;

sol = NDSolve[{EOM, IC1, IC2, μk [0] == 0.3, 
    WhenEvent[θ'[t] == 0, {μk[t] -> -μk[t], tf = t, "RestartIntegration"}]}, 
    {θ[t], θ'[t], μk[t]}, {t, ti, 10}, DiscreteVariables -> μk];

tmax = Flatten[θ[t] /. sol /. t -> "Domain"] // Last;
Plot[Evaluate[{θ[t], θ'[t], μk[t]} /. sol], {t, ti, tmax}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Note that the computation terminates with a `NDSolve::ndsz` error.  Basically, the computation has become unstable.  `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` does not help.  Incidentally, `"RestartIntegration"` has no substantive effect in this computation and can be omitted.

**Improved Solution**

Based on additional information provided by the OP in comments below and in the question itself, a better approach is

```
g = 981/100; R = 1; ti = 0; m = 3/10; μ = 3/10;

EOM =  -μ Sign[θ'[t]] (R θ'[t]^2 + g Sin[θ[t]]) + g Cos[θ[t]] == R θ''[t];
IC1 =  θ'[0] == 0;  IC2 =  θ[0] == 0;

sol = NDSolve[{EOM, IC1, IC2}, {θ[t], θ'[t]}, {t, ti, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];

Plot[Evaluate[{θ[t], θ'[t], μ  Sign[θ'[t]]} /. sol], {t, ti, tmax}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

The two solutions are identical until `θ'[t] == 0` at `t == 2.062520756856687159564857914`.  In the earlier computation, `WhenEvent` causes `μk` to reverse sign, even though `θ'[t]` does not, thereby introducing negative friction.  I have tried numerous `WhenEvent` options, as well as `WorkingPrecision` as high as `60` to resolve this issue, but without success. In conclusion, only the second solution is credible physically.

Comment: +1. Two remarks: (1) The upper limit of integration can be `Infinity`, but one cannot actually integrate to infinity. Usually one adds an event that will `"StopIntegration"`, if the stopping time is unknown. (In this case, your solution seems the right approach.) (2) My guess, based on $y'=\pm y^2$, is that the solution blows up (singularity) once `θ'[t]^2` grows too large, rather than numerical instability.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to study the dependence of the model on the parameters, but even for a small value of the parameter $\mu k$ there is no convergence of the solution to the limiting value of $\pi/2$, since this is the point of unstable equilibrium. Below is a model and data showing the transition through a point of unstable equilibrium.

```
g = 981/100; R = 1; ti = 0; tf = 20;
f[x1_?NumberQ, x_?NumberQ] := -\[Mu]k*(R x1^2 + g Sin[x])
sol = Block[{\[Mu]k = 1/20}, 
   NDSolve[{R \[Theta]''[t] == 
      f[\[Theta]'[t], \[Theta][t]] + g Cos[\[Theta][t]], \[Theta]'[
       0] == 0, \[Theta][0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[\[Theta]'[t] == 0, \[Mu]k = -\[Mu]k; 
      "RestartIntegration"]}, {\[Theta], \[Theta]'}, {t, ti, tf}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30]];


{Plot[Evaluate[\[Theta][t] /. sol], {t, ti, tf}], 
 Plot[Evaluate[\[Theta]'[t] /. sol], {t, ti, tf}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is curious, here is the final product of the problem on which I was working.  I found joy in the solution, so here you go:

[image]

```
muk = 0.3; mus = 0.4; g = 9.81; R = 1; ti = 0; thi = 0; thf = 0; sgn = 1; 
n=10^3; cnt = 0;
thList = {}; thdList = {}; TimeList = {};
th1 = ArcTan[1/mus];
th2 = Pi - th1;
While[True,
 cnt = cnt + 1;
 EOM =  \[Theta]''[t] + sgn muk \[Theta]'[t]^2 + 
    g/R (sgn muk Sin[\[Theta][t]] - Cos[\[Theta][t]]) == 0;
 IC1 =  \[Theta]'[ti] == 0;  IC2 =  \[Theta][ti] == thi;
 sol = NDSolve[{EOM, IC1, IC2, 
    WhenEvent[\[Theta]'[t] == 0, tf = t; "StopIntegration"]}, \[Theta][t], 
{t,
     ti, \[Infinity]}];
 \[Theta] = \[Theta][t] /. sol;
 thd = D[\[Theta][t] /. sol, t];
 a = Flatten[Table[\[Theta], {t, ti, tf, (tf - ti)/n}]];
 b = Flatten[Table[thd, {t, ti, tf, (tf - ti)/n}]];
 time = Flatten[Table[t, {t, ti, tf, (tf - ti)/n}]];
 AppendTo[thList, a];
 AppendTo[thdList, b];
 AppendTo[TimeList, time];
 Clear[\[Theta], thd, a, b, time];
 ti = tf;
 thi = (\[Theta][t] /. sol /. t -> tf)[[1]];
 If[thi > Pi/2, sgn = -1, sgn = 1];
 If[th1 < thi < th2, Break[]];
 If[cnt == 20, {Break[], Print["count limit reached"]}];]
thList = Flatten[thList];
thdList = Flatten[thdList];
TimeList = Flatten[TimeList];
thData = Thread[{TimeList, thList}];
thdData = Thread[{TimeList, thdList}];
SetOptions[ListPlot, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Cambria", FontSize -> 12}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True];
ListPlot[{thData, thdData}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> {"\[Theta][t]  (rad)", "thd[t]  (rad/s)"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time  (s)", ""}, PlotLabel -> "Slider Phenomenon", 
 PlotStyle -> {Lighter[Red, 0.3], Lighter[Blue, 0.3]}]
Print["The System Comes to Rest:  {{ thf = ", 
 thf = Last[thList], " rad   OR   thf = ", thf*180/Pi, "\[Degree] }}"]
```

You can change the values of "muk" and "mus" (Static and Kinetic Friction Coefficients) to observe different behavior of the slider.

This specifically is NOT an explicit answer to the question.  I used the answer by "bbgodfrey" to come to the solution to this problem.

Also, this probably can be achieved in a much simpler way, which could be explored...  Thanks.